# Why ranges::single_view use curly brace initialization for underlying value?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

According to [[range.single.view#3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.single.view#3), one of  [`std::ranges::single_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/single_view) constructors define as:

> ```
> template<class... Args>
>   requires constructible_­from<T, Args...>
> constexpr explicit single_view(in_place_t, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Initializes `value_­` as if by ­`value_­{in_­place, std​::​forward<Args>(args)...}­`.

Why the standard specifies to use of [*direct-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (`{}`) to initialize `value_`? Why not use [*direct-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (`()`) just like [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional), `std::variant`, and `std::any`?

Moreover, [`std::constructible_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from)(`std::is_constructible`) specifies that `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...)` is well-formed instead of `T obj{std::declval<Args>()...}`.

Consider the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/K4E89arEv):

```
ranges::single_view<std::vector<int>> sv(std::in_place, 100, 0);
std::cout << sv.begin()->size() << "\n";  // #1
std::optional<std::vector<int>>       op(std::in_place, 100, 0);
std::cout << op->size()         << "\n";  // #2
```

Because different initializations are used, `#1` will call the `std::vector<int>{0, 100}` and print `2`, and `#2` will call the `std::vector<int>(0, 100)` and print `100`.

Why does the standard specify using curly brace initialization for the underlying value even though it may cause inconsistencies? What is the consideration behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value_` is a *`semiregular-box`*, so its constructors are well-known and don't include an initializer-list constructor. The inconsistency doesn't arise because in this case braces and parens are equivalent - the underlying type will always be constructed with parens, because that's what the *`semiregular-box`*'s constructor is specified to do.

The behavior you are observing is a libstdc++ bug.

---

As to why the ranges clause uses list-initialization pervasively - there's no good reason, and it actually caused issues. LWG has approved a paper (P2367) that will remove misuses of list-initialization with normative impact; the remainder is tracked by [editorial issue 4593](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4593).

Comment: Bug filed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100475), thank you for your 
 explanation and link.

Comment: @TC. So does range-v3 also have this bug? Or is it just not specified relative to the standard? https://godbolt.org/z/cGznd3j4T

Answer (score 1):

> #1 will call the std::vector{0, 100}

No, it won't.

`value_` is of the type `semiregular-box<T>`, which is an exposition-only type that acts like `optional<T>`, but [with some differences](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/range.semi.wrap). But those differences don't apply here, so you can treat it as though it were just `optional<T>`.

An `initializer_list` can only be formed from a braced-init-list if all of the types of the expression are the same (or if they're convertible to some type without narrowing). But `{in_­place, std​::​forward<Args>(args)...}­` starts with the type `std::in_place_t`, which is almost certainly not one of the types of `Args`. So no `initializer_list` can be formed from it.

And even if a user does provide an `in_place_t` as `Args` (perhaps they're doing `single_view<optional<T>>` or something), it doesn't matter because `optional` (and therefore `semiregular-box`) doesn't have an `initializer_list` constructor. So it would call a matching regular constructor, just like if you'd used `()`.